# How can I remove the line that appears in an android browser?

Tags: android, html, css

I'm coding a [webpage](http://www.onacci.com/index2.php) that looks alright in computer browsers but when browsing with android it becomes a line under the logo and I want to remove the line. How can I remove the line?

[image]

```css
body {

  background-color: #00baff;

}

#container {

  height: 1698px;

  width: 1062px;

  position: relative;

}

#image {

  position: absolute;

  left: 0;

  top: 0;

}

#text {

  z-index: 100;

  position: absolute;

  //color:white;

  font-size: 24px;

  font-weight: bold;

  left: 50px;

  top: 0px;

}

#top-header {

  position: absolute;

  left: 0%;

  top: 0;

}

#searchbox {

  position: absolute;

  left: 760px;

  top: 730px;

  display: inline-block;

  z-index: 10

}

#menubar {

  position: absolute;

  display: inline-block;

  z-index: 10;

  width: 200%;

}

#menubarright {

  margin-top: 12px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.onacci.com/style/portal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>




  <!-- Menubar -->

  <div id="menubar">



    <div id="menubarcentercontainer">

      <div id="menubarleft">



      </div>



      <div id="menubarright">

        <div id="menubaruserinfo" class="menubaritem">

          <p><a href="javascript:showLoginBox();">Sign In or Sign Up</a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="menubaritem">

          <p>

            Get Onacci

          </p>

        </div>

      </div>



    </div>



  </div>




  <img id="top-header" src="https://wwwe.onacci.com/assets/onacci.png">
  <form id="searchbox" action="connect.php" method="POST">
    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- E-mail -->
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Sign-up</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
        <p class="help-block">Please provide your E-mail</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: is your webView height, wrap content...

Comment: @Mohit Thank you for the comment. Can you please elaborate? I didn't fully understand.

Comment: I mean height attribute of your web view...

Comment: And yes I agree with the answer given....there is a line in your image..

Comment: Did removing the line from the image work or were there other issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image has a line in it!.

https://wwwe.onacci.com/assets/onacci.png

Remove that line and it should work. I actually don't know why the line doesn't show up in other browsers. Maybe you're looking at it on a highres screen?